# html css Loader need to complte Position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HI friend i have one page loader but the probelm is when load the content also than loader running don't display the loaded the content i want stop loading and load the page deatils and content

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  

// site preloader -- also uncomment the div in the header and the css style for #preloader
$(window).load(function(){
 $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove();});
});

});
```

```css
  
  .js div#preloader { position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 999; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: visible; background: #333 url('http://files.mimoymima.com/images/loading.gif') no-repeat center center; }
```

```html
 
<div class="js"><!--this is supposed to be on the HTML element but codepen won't let me do it-->
  <body>
    <div id="preloader"></div>
    
    <h1>SUPER SIMPLE FULL PAGE PRELOADER</h1>
    
    <p>Works with modernizr, or you could just add your own js class to the html element using javascript</p>
    
    <p>You can make it fit your site better by generating your own image here: http://ajaxload.info/ then change the background color in the css</p>
    
    <p>The example below doesn't fade out because the pageload event isn't fireing I'm guessing? but it will on your site when your page loads.</p>
    
  </body>
  
</div><!--END: HTML element-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1)don't need To `function(){$(this).remove();}`
>
> 2)The load() method was deprecated in jQuery version 1.8 and removed in version 3.0 and occurs when a specified element has been loaded.

So,

> Use `$(document).ready(function(){});`
>
> This is to prevent any jQuery code from running before the document is finished loading.
>
> read More : https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_syntax.asp

**Full Code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {  
 $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

```css
.js div#preloader { 
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   z-index: 999;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: visible;
   background: #333 url('http://files.mimoymima.com/images/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="js">
 <h1>SUPER SIMPLE FULL PAGE PRELOADER</h1>
    <p>Works with modernizr, or you could just add your own js class to the html element using javascript</p>
    <p>You can make it fit your site better by generating your own image here: http://ajaxload.info/ then change the background color in the css</p>
    <p>The example below doesn't fade out because the pageload event isn't fireing I'm guessing? but it will on your site when your page loads.</p>
    <div id="preloader"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use any one, [`document.ready`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) is enough .No need to add `window.onload` .because both are same , (perform after document loaded)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  

 $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove();});

});
```

```css
.js div#preloader {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
  background: #333 url('http://files.mimoymima.com/images/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="js">
  <!--this is supposed to be on the HTML element but codepen won't let me do it-->

  <body>
    <div id="preloader"></div>

    <h1>SUPER SIMPLE FULL PAGE PRELOADER</h1>

    <p>Works with modernizr, or you could just add your own js class to the html element using javascript</p>

    <p>You can make it fit your site better by generating your own image here: http://ajaxload.info/ then change the background color in the css</p>

    <p>The example below doesn't fade out because the pageload event isn't fireing I'm guessing? but it will on your site when your page loads.</p>

  </body>

</div>
<!--END: HTML element-->
```